# Why is boost::optional::is_initialized() deprecated?

Tags: c++, boost, option-type

I noticed today that `boost::optional::is_initialized()` is marked as deprecated in the [Boost 1.64.0 reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/reference/header__boost_optional_optional_hpp_/header_optional_optional_values.html).  My projects are liberally sprinkled with `is_initialized()` to check if the `boost::optional` contains a value.

I don't see any other way to properly test if a `boost::optional` is initialized, am I missing something?

The `boost::optional` has a `explicit operator bool()`, meaning that I can do `if(foo){...}` if `foo` is a `boost::optional`.  However, this would give wrong results if `foo` is a `boost::optional<bool>` or some other `boost::optional<T>` where `T` is convertible to `bool`.

What does Boost expect users to do?

Comment: How about comparing it to `boost::none`? As is done in quite a few places in the Boost optional manual?

Comment: Why should it give wrong results for the `boost::optional<bool>`? For the `boost::optional<bool> a` `if(a)` gives an initialization status. `*a` - `a` value if initialized

Comment: Comparison with boost::none is advices according to [their documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/tutorial/a_note_about_optional_bool_.html).

Comment: @user2525536  It doesn't seem to advise comparison to `boost::none`.

Comment: an answer is marked correct, but "why" is never answered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> However, this would give wrong results if foo is a boost::optional or some other boost::optional where T is convertible to bool.

No, because there is no implicit conversion to the underlying type. The "truthiness"¹ of an optional *always* refers to its initialized state.

The only time you may have gotten the *impression* that implicit conversions happen is in relational operators. However, that's not doing implicit conversion to the underlying type, instead does *lifting* of the operators, explicitly.

*¹ by which I mean contextual (explicit) boolean conversion*

#### Update

Indeed for `boost::optional<bool>` there's the caveat [in pre-c++11 mode](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/tutorial/a_note_about_optional_bool_.html):

> Second, although optional<> provides a contextual conversion to bool in C++11, this falls back to an implicit conversion on older compilers

In that case it is clearly better to explicitly compare to `boost::none`.

Comment: TL;DR to that: `isTrue` -> `o && *o`; `isFalse` -> `o && !*o`; `isUndef` -> `!o`

Comment: Except, it's really just `isTrue -> o == true;`, `isFalse -> o == false;`. All of which is equivalent, due to [lifted/mixed operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/tutorial/relational_operators.html)

Answer (score 3):

As of this writing, Boost [1.72](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/reference/header__boost_optional_optional_hpp_/header_optional_optional_values.html) supports a "has_value" method, which is not deprecated.

Under the hood, it just calls "is_initialized" though.
See [the code](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/boost/optional/optional.hpp):

```
bool has_value() const BOOST_NOEXCEPT { return this->is_initialized() ; }
```

That aside, another convenient trick I've seen is the `!!` idiom.
Eg:

```
boost::optional<Foo> x = ...
MY_ASSERT(!!x, "x must be set");
```

It's essentially the same as writing `(bool)x` or the even more prohibitively verbose `static_cast<bool>(x)`.

Aside: it is a bit odd that `is_initialized` was deprecated, then an exactly equivalent function with a different name got added later. I suspect it was for compatibility with C++17's [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_bool).

Comment: `has_value()` was added in Boost Release 1.68: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/relnotes.html.

Answer (score 0):

For future references, as stated [on boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/tutorial/relational_operators.html), you can compare like this from now on:

```
boost::optional<int> oN = boost::none;
boost::optional<int> o0 = 0;
boost::optional<int> o1 = 1;

assert(oN != o0);
assert(o1 != oN);
assert(o0 != o1);
assert(oN == oN);
assert(o0 == o0);
```

You could even do:

```
if(oN != 2){}
```

or simply to check if the value is set:

```
if(oN){}
```